# In Pogress icon in Jenkins reset (corruptd)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed material theme for Jenkins, but I wanted to reset it, so I uninstalled the theme, but it seems not all components are properly uninstalled. The in progress icon in Jenkins is completely broken. As can be seen in the image there is an outer in progress icon which is revolving around the main icon. Please if someone can help me with this.

[Jenkins error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98GRP.jpg)

Jenkins version - Jenkins 2.289.2

Comment: [JENKINS-65808](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65808). Next time, would help if you include version#s in your submission.

Comment: Here is the [workaround](https://github.com/afonsof/jenkins-material-theme/issues/183) for fixing the issue.